# Split and create a new line after a certain condition in a string

Tags: python, split

So here's my Python code:

```
my_name = "Hello<split>my<split>name<split>is<split>Max"
print my_name
```

Results would be:

```
Hello<split>my<split>name<split>is<split>Max
```

But I would like the results to look like this instead:

```
Hello
my
name
is
Max
```

The tag "split" was removed and a new line was created.
Any ideas on how to about doing that in Python?

Comment: `my_name.replace('<split>', '\n')` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> my_name = "Hello<split>my<split>name<split>is<split>Max"
>>> 
>>> for s in my_name.split('<split>'):
...     print s
... 
Hello
my
name
is
Max
```

If you want the result as a single string you can use [`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) as others have mentioned:

```
>>> import os
>>> my_name.replace('<split>', os.linesep)
'Hello\nmy\nname\nis\nMax'
```

Or you can rejoin the split:

```
>>> os.linesep.join(my_name.split('<split>'))
'Hello\nmy\nname\nis\nMax'
```

Though I would prefer the replacing method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked flawlessly.
Also thanks to other answers, they've worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
print my_name.replace("<split>","\n")
```

displays

```
Hello
my
name
is
Max
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print my_name.replace("<split>", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string using the built in function `split` Here is an example that uses a generator object to append a new line to every substring:

```
my_name_split = [s + '\n' for s in my_name.split("<split>")]
```

alternatively, if you just want to print the split string without actually creating a new variable, you can simply replace `"<split>"` with `"\n"` using `replace`:

```
print my_name.replace("<split>","\n")
```

Note that this does not actually change the value of my_name.